# Please help me with start hybris server

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When I run this command "hybrisserver.bat"  I get the following error 
"\platform\tomcat/conf/wrapper-debug.conf was unexpected at this time".This issue happened after I reinstall **hybris sap**.Please let me know if you have an idea how to solve this issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **wrapper-debug.conf** is used when starting Hybris in debug mode(i.e **hybrisserver.bat debug**) while the **wrapper.conf** is used when starting Hybris in standard mode(i.e **hybrisserver.bat**).

These two files contain things like JVM options that are used during Server Startup and also these files are generated during build.

Because of that I would suggest to perform a build(i.e **ant clean all**) and then start the server again.